# Python TicTacToe GUI Game Crash when Tie

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, handle, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to build a simple Tic Tac Toe game using python, almost there now except that the game crash whenever it is a tie

So when it is tie, the last empty square clicked won't change color like others did, and the window freeze, clicks are disabled....  I have no idea the reason is

My entire code is here:

```
import tkinter
import random


class Game(object):
    """
    Enter the class docstring here
    """
    block_size = 100
    def __init__(self, parent):
        parent.title('Tic Tac Toe')
        self.parent = parent

        self.initialize_game()

    def initialize_game(self):
        # These are the initializations that need to happen
        # at the beginning and after restarts
        self.board = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]  # game board as a instance variable
        self.map = {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2, (1, 0): 3, (1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 5, (2, 0): 6, (2, 1): 7,
                    (2, 2): 8}  # map to self.board
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.parent)
        self.top_frame.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)

        # add restart button on top frame
        restart_button = tkinter.Button(self.top_frame, text='Restart', width=20,
                                        command=self.restart)
        restart_button.pack()  # register restart_button with geometry manager

        # create bottom frame for group the label below
        self.bottom_frame=tkinter.Frame(self.parent)
        self.bottom_frame.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

        # create label for displaying game result text
        self.my_lbl=tkinter.Label(self.bottom_frame,text=None)
        self.my_lbl.pack()

        # create a canvas to draw our board on the top frame
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.top_frame,
                                     width=self.block_size * 3,
                                     height=self.block_size * 3)

        # draw 3x3 visible blocks on the canvas
        for ro in range(3):
            for col in range(3):

                self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.block_size * col,
                                             self.block_size * ro,
                                             self.block_size * (col + 1),
                                             self.block_size * (ro + 1),fill='white')

        # bind entire canvas with left click  handler (play function)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.play)
        self.canvas.pack()                  # register canvas with a geometry manager

    def board_full(self):
        if None not in self.board:
            return True            # true for full
        else:
            return False           # false for not full


    def possible_moves(self):
        """return: list of possible moves"""
        possible_moves = []                 # list for possible moves
        for i in range(0, 9):
            if self.board[i] is None:       # if cell un-taken
                possible_moves.append(i)    # append the cell number to list
            else:
                pass              # cell taken, don't append
        return possible_moves     # return list of possible moves

    def pc_move(self):
        m = True
        while m:
            pc_move = random.randint(0, 8)    # random generate a number from 0 to 8
            if pc_move in self.possible_moves():  # if the number is a possible move
                self.board[pc_move] = 'O'         # mark O
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(tagOrId=(pc_move+1),fill='blue')
                m = False                        # exit loop
            else:                                # not a possible movie
                continue                          # re-do
        return self

    def draw_out(self):
        """to be deleted"""
        print(self.board[0:3])
        print(self.board[3:6])
        print(self.board[6:9])

    def play(self, event):  # This method is invoked when the user clicks on a square.
        """
        when the player clicks on a un-taken square, this method first translate cursor into cell number,
        then update game board and check game result based on condition
        :parameter: click
        :return: updated game object
        """
        # after the click: part 1     human play first
        print('clicked', event.y, event.x)  # to be deleted  show window coordinate
        cx = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)   # window coordinate to canvas coordinate
        cy = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)   # window coordinate to canvas coordinate
        cid = self.canvas.find_closest(cx,cy)[0] # find the closet colored widget by click point
        my_move = self.map[(cy // self.block_size, cx // self.block_size)]  # map cursor
        if self.board[my_move] is None:            # check if cell is empty
            self.board[my_move] = 'X'              # if cell empty mark X for my play
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(cid,fill='green') # fill green color for player
            #self.canvas.itemconfigure(tagOrId=(my_move+1),fill='green')
        else:              # if the cell taken, do nothing until click on empty square
            return None
                                      #  check game result and board full:
        self.draw_out()                          # DEBUGGING line
        if self.check_game()is not None:
            print(self.check_game())             # DEBUGGING line
        else:
            pass
        # part 2: while not filled, PC make one move right after my move:
        self.possible_moves()                     # check possible moves for PC
        self.pc_move()                            # pc make move
        self.draw_out()                           # DELETE LATER
        # part3: check game result and board full
        if self.check_game()is not None:
            print(self.check_game())             # DEBUGGING line
        else:
            pass
        return self  # when board is filled, return

    def check_game(self):
        """
        Check if the game is win or lost or a tie
        Return:  win, lose, tie, none """
        result=None
        if (self.board[0] == self.board[1] == self.board[2] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[3] == self.board[4] == self.board[5] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[6] == self.board[7] == self.board[8] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[0] == self.board[3] == self.board[6] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[1] == self.board[4] == self.board[7] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[2] == self.board[5] == self.board[8] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[0] == self.board[4] == self.board[8] == 'X') or (
                            self.board[2] == self.board[4] == self.board[6] == 'X'):
            result = 'You win!'  # player win
            self.my_lbl.configure(text=result)
        elif (self.board[0] == self.board[1] == self.board[2] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[3] == self.board[4] == self.board[5] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[6] == self.board[7] == self.board[8] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[0] == self.board[3] == self.board[6] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[1] == self.board[4] == self.board[7] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[2] == self.board[5] == self.board[8] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[0] == self.board[4] == self.board[8] == 'O') or (
                            self.board[2] == self.board[4] == self.board[6] == 'O'):
            result = 'You lost!'  # player lose
            self.my_lbl.config(text=result)
        elif self.board_full()is True:
                result = 'A tie!'  # tie
                self.my_lbl.configure(text=result)
        else:
            pass
        return result


    def restart(self):
        """ Reinitialize the game and board after restart button is pressed """
        self.top_frame.destroy()
        self.bottom_frame.destroy()
        self.initialize_game()


def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()  # Instantiate a root window
    my_game = Game(root)  # Instantiate a Game object
    root.mainloop()  # Enter the main event loop


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Show the error that gives you.

Comment: I have no error message(well.. one of the problem here) run debugger on the whole program, nothing came up....kind of stuck on this...oh, forgot to mention that the crash always happens when there only one empty square left on board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

`def pc_move(self):
    m = True
    while m:`

With

`while not self.board_full():`

And where you set `m` back to false `break`, instead.

The reason your code did not work is because if `if pc_move in self.possible_moves():` returns false, you ran:

`else:
    continue`

until the end of time.

Comment: Tried this , not working.  It only end the game in one move,because after my move, program will takes all other spots at once, result will always be lost.

Comment: @shadow, I apologize for the oversight, please take a look at my edit and see if it helps you.

Comment: Indeed the problem was that when the player occupies the last square, the computer tries to choose a square as well, but since there are no empty squares left, ends up in an infinite loop. The loop you have with m is fine, but needs an additional check for a full board. Maybe better: only call the function if the board is not full, and make an assert at the beginning of pc_move() to get an error meassage if this precondition is not met.

Comment: @MeetTitan  Thanks a lot for correcting my code, I did not realize that I should check board_full before the move even I wrote in one of the comment line... Thanks

Comment: @physicalattraction  yes, absolutely right. I totally missed that part in pc_move

Comment: @shadow, No problem. Let me add to this a late welcome to stack overflow. I hope you enjoy your stay.